# How can I use jquery datepicker on an input that is not loaded yet?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am experimenting with the Datepicker widget in jQuery UI. The following code works just fine, as expected:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the form with the date input field will be loaded dynamically with an Ajax call. This means that the input id `#datepicker` doesn't exist when the page loads. I have understood that I can use the `.on` event in jQuery for elements that is not loaded yet. But that requires an event to be triggered. So, can I solve this in a similar way with Datepicker? How can I initialize the datepicker after the form is loaded dynamically?

Comment: Can you show us the code that _doesn't_ work instead/as well as the code which does? In short you apply `.datpicker()` the same time as you put the field onscreen.

Comment: Thank's @Jamiec... Silly me. Of course I simply apply the datepicker in the Ajax Call where the form is loaded and displayed... Why didn't I think of that :-D

Comment: Yes you can apply the DatePicker once the element is loaded, can use `.ready()` or just after it is appended.